# What's the difference between a reverse proxy and a gateway?

Tags: security, proxy, gateway

I know the difference between a forward and reverse proxy, but am not clear on how a reverse proxy is different from a gateway.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

A **gateway** is about **routing**. 
When a computer wants to communicate with another computer in a different network, it usually uses the gateway to get out of its own network. Gateways take care of routing data packets between separate networks.

A **proxy** is about **representing** another computer(s)/server(s) in a network. 
 Usually it is done for different purposes like load balancing, caching, access blocking, etc. The client is unaware that it talks to proxy instead of to the actual server (***reverse proxy***).

Answer (score -1):

A gateway is a network point that acts as an entrance to another network.

A reverse proxy is where a proxy server retrieves information being sent from one or more servers.

The proxy server is essentially asking the gateway for permission for information to enter the network.

Internet (Information) --> gateway --> proxy server --> human (GUI)

Comment: but don't gateways often act as proxy servers themselves?